# Trying to convert .txt to PDF using convertapi.com - Python 3.2.2

Tags: python, api, pdf, text

I'm am new to python and programming in general. I am trying to convert a .txt file to pdf, I searched but could not find a library for doing this that works out of the box with python 3.2.2 so I am using a web service.

This is my code: I am getting "File" parameter cannot be null

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, http.client, os
#import requests

#ejemplo txt
txt = open("test.txt", 'rb')

def txtPdf(txt):
    url = "http://do.convertapi.com/text2Pdf"
    archivo =  open("temp.pdf", "wb")
    valores = {"File": txt}

    datos = urllib.parse.urlencode(valores).encode("utf-8")
    solicitar = urllib.request.urlopen(url, data = datos)
    archivo.write(solicitar.read())
    archivo.close()

txtPdf(txt)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy, if you can use requests:

```
import requests

txtPdf(filename):
    url = "http://do.convertapi.com/text2Pdf"
    archivo =  open("temp.pdf", "wb")

    response = requests.post(url,
        files={'filename': open(filename,'rb')}
    )

    archivo.write(response.content)
    archivo.close()

txtPdf('test.txt')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
   So I tried to get requests working but failed, it seems to me that it doesn't work with python 3.2.2. If I do use something like requests I need it to be integrated with the program's script files because my program needs to work on any computer with python 3.2.2. So does anyone know if requests is compatible with my version of python and if yes how would i go about using it based on my needs? Thanks again!

Comment: Never Mind. I figured it out! Thanks Again saved my day! For any other newbies reading this i just had to download the source and place it with my other files, then i could import it

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'https://do.convertapi.com/Text2Pdf';
$fp = fopen("convertedfile.pdf", "w");
$postdata =  array('ApiKey' => $apiKey, 'file'=>"@/example.txt");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
$headers = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```